# Can't get rid of __pycache__

Tags: git, gitignore

After noticing the pycache folder i decided to ignore them adding **pycache**\ in gitignore but it doesn't seem to work (it works in the root folder but not recursively in subfolder utilities) ...
Any idea ?

[image]

Comment: why have you added `__pycache__/` and not `__pycache__`?

Comment: but anyway, .gitignore works for new files, but if you've already previously added some files you'll need to remove those separately

Comment: btw u can use https://www.toptal.com/developers/gitignore to generate git ignore files (just type in IDES coding languages etc and it generates the text

Comment: @eis: there's nothing wrong with using `__pycache__/` here, but using `__pycache__\` is a bad idea.